# populating listbox from textbox

Tags: c#, listbox

I am trying to get the name of the Investment to appear in the listbox for stock but the code(which I used earlier in the program) doesn't seem to work.

```
   namespace JamesClemens_FinalProject
 {
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    ArrayList account;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        account = new ArrayList();
    }

    //here we set up our add customer button from the first tab
    //when the information is filled in and the button is clicked
    //the name on the account will be put in the combobox on the second tab
    private void btnAddCustomer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            CustomerAccount aCustomerAccount = new CustomerAccount(txtAccountNumber.Text, txtCustomerName.Text,
            txtCustomerAddress.Text, txtPhoneNumber.Text);
            account.Add(aCustomerAccount);

            cboClients.Items.Add(aCustomerAccount.GetCustomerName());
            ClearText();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Make sure every text box is filled in!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }
    }


    private void ClearText()
    {
        txtAccountNumber.Clear();
        txtCustomerName.Clear();
        txtCustomerAddress.Clear();
        txtPhoneNumber.Clear();
    }


    private void cboClients_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        CustomerAccount custAccount = account[cboClients.SelectedIndex] as CustomerAccount;
 if(custAccount != null)
 {
     txtAccountNumberTab2.Text = custAccount.GetAccountNumber();
     txtCustomerNameTab2.Text = custAccount.GetCustomerName();
     txtCustomerAddressTab2.Text = custAccount.GetCustomerAddress();
     txtCustomerPhoneNumberTab2.Text = custAccount.GetCustomerPhoneNo();
}
    }
```

This is the code giving me trouble, it keeps saying that "new Stock" does not contain a constructor that takes four arguments.

```
  private void btnAddStock_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Stock aStock = new Stock(txtInvestmentID.Text, txtInvestmentName.Text,      txtInvestmentSymbol.Text,
                int.Parse(txtInvestmentShares.Text));
            account.Add(aStock);
            lstStock.Items.Add(aStock.GetInvestmentName());
            ClearText();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Make sure every text box is filled in!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }
    }
```

does anyone know why it's not letting me use the Stock class?

Here's the stock class like you asked for.
        public class Stock:Investment
       {
        //attributes
        private double stockPrice;

```
    //constructors
    public Stock()
    {
    }

    public Stock(string anInvestmentID, string anInvestmentName, string anInvestmentSymbol,
        int anInvestmentShare, CustomerAccount aCustomer, double aStockPrice)
        : base(anInvestmentID, anInvestmentName, anInvestmentSymbol, anInvestmentShare)
    {
        SetStockPrice(aStockPrice);
    }

   //
    public Stock(string anInvestmentID, string anInvestmentName, string anInvestmentSymbol,
        int anInvestmentShare, CustomerAccount aCustomer, double aStockPrice)
    {
        SetInvestmentID(anInvestmentID);
        SetInvestmentName(anInvestmentName);
        SetInvestmentSymbol(anInvestmentSymbol);
        SetInvestmentShare(anInvestmentShare);
        SetStockPrice(aStockPrice);
    }

    //set accessors
    public void SetStockPrice(double aStockPrice)
    {
        stockPrice = aStockPrice;
    }

    //get accessors
    public double GetStockPrice()
    {
        return stockPrice;
    }
```

Comment: Your Stock object doesn't take four arguments and you're using four arguments.  Try posting the constructor of your Stock class.

Comment: Your Stock object takes six arguments or zero arguments.  It looks like your base class Investment is taking four arguments.

Comment: Okay, i realize what i did.  I set up a "stockPrice" in the Stock class and then added that under the button. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Please actually read the error messages you get; it makes programming much easier.

The error message is pretty clear:

```
"new Stock" does not contain a constructor that takes four arguments.
```

You don't have a constructor in your `Stock` class that takes **four arguments**.

Look at the three constructors you posted in your `Stock` class. Count the number of parameters you need to pass into each constructor. Is there one that accepts four arguments only? I see one that takes no arguments, and two that each take six arguments.

Trying to understand the actual text of error messages will help you a lot in the future writing code. Most (not all, but *most*) error messages have meaningful content that points you to the actual problem. :)